# Who wins the game?

Tags: vb.net, function

I am trying to define a function that returns a value indicating whether the winner of my game has been determined, if yes, who the winner is, and after the player's turn, update the remaining number of sticks and use the function defined above to check if a winner has been determined and if the game should continue.

I am creating a game in VB.NET that's called pick up sticks, it involves two players who take turns to play. Players can start with any number of sticks that they both agree upon before game. At each player’s turn, the player must pick at least one stick and at most half the sticks. Whoever picks up the last stick loses the game. I need to implement this game so that a player can play against the computer

This is me trying to write the computer's turn:

```
Private Sub ComputerTurn() 'change 6 with setNum whatever sticks number was agreed upon
    Dim ComputerNum As Integer
    'ComputerNum = Int((SetNumInputTB * Rnd()) - SetNumInputTB / 2)
    MsgBox("The computer picked " & ComputerNum & " sticks")
End Sub
```

I think I should use an if statement or a for loop but I'm not sure how to implement the right mathmatics in it

Comment: "I'm not sure how to implement the right mathmatics in it" - neither are we because it is your game and you are developing the strategy. In addition, you have only provided a stub of code and you are expecting us to do the whole algorithm. Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Developing a [mcve] for specific problems will increase your chances of getting a reasonable answer.

Comment: You'll need a variable declared at class/form level that tracks how many sticks are left.  Your isGameOver() function can simply return whether that variable is equal to zero. The loser is whomever went last; use a boolean to track if it's player1's turn or not.

Comment: The main body loop would then simply be `While Not IsGameOver()`...

Comment: It would be easiest if you just link to your homework question if it's available online

Comment: Also, by the type of question being asked, is this a **Console** application?...or a WinForms app?  Or something else?...

Comment: I already have a game like that in asp you allow the player to select max 3 sticks then press the button, the AI has to pickup a random of 1-3 sticks (if there is less than 4 sticks at the end and it's AI turn take all the sticks so that the AI can win), the rules of the game says the winner is the one who picks last sticks, so when there is no sticks left, the last player is the winner. Keep track of who is currently playing now with an INT like 0 is player 1 is AI, and when gameover() you will know who won based on that int

Answer (score -1):

Well you are going to need a lot more that just that in the computer turn. You will need to update how many sticks are left in the pile. Also depending on if you want the computer to play optimal strategy then you will have to add logic into the function.

Umm I do think that the game is pretty silly because the person who goes first wins every time. They pick up one less than half (ex start with 30). So they pick up 14 and 16 are left. Next turn the other player can pick up at most 15 and at least 1 stick so the next turn player one can clear the board except one stick

If you mean they can only pick up half the remaining pile the the logic will be a little more complicated but still not too bad.

Comment: Next turn other player can pickup at most 8 (half of  16 sticks remained after first turn)